# How to understand "not necessarily to DML statements" from mysql docs?

Tags: mysql, innodb

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-consistent-read.html

> **Note** 
>   The snapshot of the database state applies to SELECT statements
>   within a transaction, not necessarily to DML statements. If you insert
>   or modify some rows and then commit that transaction, a DELETE or
>   UPDATE statement issued from another concurrent REPEATABLE READ
>   transaction could affect those just-committed rows, even though the
>   session could not query them. If a transaction does update or delete
>   rows committed by a different transaction, those changes do become
>   visible to the current transaction. For example, you might encounter a
>   situation like the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(c1) FROM t1 WHERE c1 = 'xyz'; -- Returns 0: no rows match.
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE c1 = 'xyz'; -- Deletes several rows recently committed by other transaction.

SELECT COUNT(c2) FROM t1 WHERE c2 = 'abc'; -- Returns 0: no rows match.
UPDATE t1 SET c2 = 'cba' WHERE c2 = 'abc'; -- Affects 10 rows: another txn just committed 10 rows with 'abc' values.
SELECT COUNT(c2) FROM t1 WHERE c2 = 'cba'; -- Returns 10: this txn can now see the rows it just updated.
```

Comment: Did you try clicking on the `DML` link? It links to the glossary and explains what it means.

Comment: @Barmar Sure, but it also mentions about INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE - this is why I'm here to ask...

Comment: @Barmar ...and also this source link https://blogs.oracle.com/mysqlinnodb/entry/repeatable_read_isolation_level_in is about SELECT as an initiator of snapshot

Comment: If my answer isn't helping you, you need to clarify the question. Just posting a quote from the documentation isn't really a clear question.

Comment: Use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` whenever you expect to modifying _those_ rows.  This will (I think) prevent the strangeness of the example given.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Glossary](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/glossary.html#glos_dml):

> **DML**
>   Data manipulation language, a set of SQL statements for performing insert, update, and delete operations.

In other words, they're the SQL statements that modify data in tables, as opposed to just retrieving it as `SELECT` does.

What that paragraph is saying, as shown in the example below it, is that modification queries can affect rows that were committed in another transaction, even if that took place after you started your current transaction. And when that happens, your transaction's snapshot is updated to include those rows.

Comment: I completely understand that, but first sentence in the note section from the question above is about snapshot and SELECT, but next is confusing...

Comment: As long as all you do are `SELECT` statements, you'll keep seeing the same data -- that's the snapshot. But if you perform any DML statements, changes from other transactions can leak into your transaction.